# How do I reference Table names in my ODBC connected object?

Tags: r, odbc

I made a connection to an ODBC database

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "DTAM QA")
```

I listed out all the tables to confirm

```
dbListTables(con)
```

But how do I get Column Headers from my tables within 'con' / my connection object?

Let's say I wanted to get all Column Headers from a table [MobileDevicesTable] within 'con', what would the syntax look like?

I'm thinking it'd look like this, using a function like 'colnames' below, but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated :)

```
tableForMobileDevices <- colnames(con.MobileDevicesTable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ODBC is a wrapper around SQL, so the easiest way to get things is to expressly ask for them in a query of some sort.

But if all you want is the column headings of the table, there are built in methods within ODBC that take care of these common needs. So, you could use this:

```
tableForMobileDevices<-dbListFields(con, "MobileDevicesTable")
```

You pass it your connection and the name of the table and get back the field names

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It seems the common syntax is function(connection, "table_name")

Comment: You are very welcome! And that is the most common method. And you can pass queries into the  `df <- dbSendQuery(con, 'regular sql query here')` just like you would with your flavor of SQL and save them into an R data frame